# Iterating over a DF to make plots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have da DF with 4 columns:

```
    Date      |  Year  | Month | Production
  2010-01-01     2010      1        10
  2010-02-01     2010      2        20
                 2010     ...       30
                 2010      12       33
                 2011      1        44
                 2020     ...      ....
```

`column [Date]` is the index.  I am ploting a graph this way:

```
plt.plot(df.index, df['Production'])
```

I get a plot from years 2010 to 2020. Working just fine.

What i want to do is to plot a graph by year, monthly like this:

```
for year 2010:  plot months X Production
for year 2011:  plot months X Production
```

How can i iterate over my DF to plot all this graphs in 3 graphs per row, for example?

I tried:

```
years = df['Year'].unique()
for year in years:
    plt.plot(years[i], df['Production'])
```

but dosent work!

I want a plot like the image below:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 3 graphs per row?

Comment: @Corralien I updated the post adding a image of what I expect to get.  The x-label still Months. Thanks

Comment: do you tried the proposed solution? It's important to accept (only) if an answer fits to your need. From SO: "Accepting a solution will mark your question as resolved and will make it easier for others in the Community to find valuable content and answers without having to read through an entire topic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the job:

```
nplt = df['Year'].nunique()
ncols = 3
nrows = nplt // ncols + (1 if nplt % ncols else 0)

# Create figure and subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(15, 15))
fig.suptitle('Production')

# Plot one year per subplot
for ax, (year, dfy) in zip(axs.flat, df.groupby('Year')):
    ax.set_title(year)
    ax.plot(dfy['Month'], dfy['Production'])

# Remove unused subplots
for ax in axs.flat[nplt:]:
    fig.delaxes(ax)
```

[image: Production plot - 3 columns]

You can use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for a better rendering.

Comment: @StatsPy, is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks Corralien.  Working great !